# Looping through a list of fetch() calls

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through a bunch of data and make asynch calls. However, I'm not getting the syntax right

```
async function getEmailData(conversationId){
    fetch(aysynch)
    .then(response => {return response.json(); })
    .then(data => {
        dictionary = {}
        console.log(data)
        var info = data.Body.ResponseMessages.Items[0].Conversation.ConversationNodes[0].Items[0]
        console.log(info)
        var conversationId = info.ConversationId.Id
        var from = info.From.Mailbox.EmailAddress
        var to = info.ToRecipients.map(function(recipient) {return recipient.EmailAddress})
        var date = info.DateTimeReceived
        dictionary[conversationId] = {'from':from, 'to': to, 'date': date}
        return dictionary
    })
}

x = [listOfIds] //10 in total

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i].ConversationId.Id)
    let response = await getEmailData(x[i].ConversationId.Id)
    let data = await response
    console.log(data)
}
```

This is printing out all of the ID's and then grabbing the list id in `x` and running that one 10 times. How do I make the aysnch request for each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- The function `getEmailData` is not returning anything. You need to `return` the result of the promise chain.
- `async` has no use if you don't use `await` inside such a function
- `await` outside an `async` function is invalid.
- `await response` is not useful when `response` is already the result of an `await`
- declare your variables (with `let`, `var`, `const`)

So do this:

```
function getEmailData(conversationId){
    return fetch(aysynch)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const dictionary = {};
        console.log(data);
        var info = data.Body.ResponseMessages.Items[0].Conversation.ConversationNodes[0].Items[0];
        console.log(info);
        var conversationId = info.ConversationId.Id;
        var from = info.From.Mailbox.EmailAddress;
        var to = info.ToRecipients.map(recipient => recipient.EmailAddress);
        var date = info.DateTimeReceived;
        dictionary[conversationId] = {from, to, date};
        return dictionary;
    });
}

(async function() {
    let x = [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 13, 23, 22, 24, 19]; //10 in total

    for (let i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        console.log(x[i].ConversationId.Id);
        let data = await getEmailData(x[i].ConversationId.Id);
        console.log(data);
    }
})(); // Immediately invoked
```

Comment: this makes sense. Still running into the issue its using the same ID every time. I updated my question to show the results of your answer

Comment: There was one more variable which you had not  declared (and so it was global): `dictionary`. I updated the answer. This is something to pay attention to. Never start using variables without declaring them. Use `"use strict"` to make this a mandatory habit.

Comment: I updated dictionary to be a `const`, but it looks like its still trying the last ID on every fetch call. Good call on naming conventions!

Comment: Please debug to verify what `conversationId` is, right after `var conversationId = `. If there it is always the same, the problem is in your server code.

Comment: yea, I think that's where something is wrong! doing that now.

Comment: I'm not actually hitting my server, I'm hitting an exchange server trying to ingest some email data

Comment: OK, but anyway, if indeed you are getting the same id over and over again from the `fetch` response, then really that is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: BTW, what is `aysynch` that you pass to `fetch`? If it is always the same, then is it not normal that you get the same response each time?

Comment: looks like this is what is happening! thank you for helping me debug that. Your answer remains the same, it helped me with something that I would have had to figure out :-)

Comment: I'll update my question to show what is happening. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: added the results...any thoughts on why it might be getting stuck on the first ID? I copy pasted the fetch call into another window and searched for that ID just to make sure it wasn't hardcoded anywhere in there.

Comment: fml, I figured it out, naming convention....I added `conversationID` in the sting concatenation not `conversationId` and `conversationID` was stored as that one string...

Comment: OK, Now I think you should remove the edits from your question, as it is bending the question towards that whole other problem, and it uses code from answers, which makes the answers look irrelevant.

Comment: will do! thanks! btw, is there a way I can send you a DM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191411/discussion-between-trincot-and-morgan-allen).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `let`. You are are declaring a global variable `i`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i].ConversationId.Id)
    let response = await getEmailData(x[i].ConversationId.Id)
    let data = await response
    console.log(data)
}
```